# How can I transfer photos from a Sony Ericsson V600i to the computer?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, photos, mobile-phone

Do I have to download a proprietary program (most likely bloatware) from Sony Ericsson or is it possible to only install USB drivers and mount the phone to the file system or something similar?

**UPDATE:** I've downloaded and installed the USB drivers for the V600i phone but they don't mount the phone as a drive in the file system. There is however a OBEX driver installed and i've tried using the [OBEX commander](http://intradarma.com/OBEXCommander.html) to transfer the files. That does not work because it won't connect to the phone, but it can identify it. I've also tried an open source application called [Cs-OpenOBEX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cs-obexftp/) which doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the [drivers](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/support/softwaredownloads/detailed/usbdrivers/v600i?lc=en&cc=za) [suggested](https://superuser.com/questions/32527/how-can-i-transfer-photos-from-a-sony-ericsson-v600i-to-the-computer/32533#32533) by [ChrisF](https://superuser.com/users/289/chrisf) and [Sony Ericsson PC Suite](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/support/softwaredownloads/detailed/pcsuite/v600i?lc=en&cc=za) I finally managed to transfer files from the phone to the computer. I could not make it work with only the USB drivers or in combination with OBEX Commander or Cs-OpenOBEX which is a pity.

Even using the PC Suite the experience was less than satisfying since it keeps crashing on me. I'm on Vista but that is a supported platform for PC Suite.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a flavour of Windows you should (theoretically) be able to mount the phone as a USB harddrive and access it that way. It should state this in the phone's manual.

However, the only way to test this is to connect the phone and see what happens.

I've done a quick search and found [this page](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/support/softwaredownloads/detailed/usbdrivers/v600i?lc=en&cc=za) which has the USB drivers for your phone. It's a 0.2Mb download, so I don't think that there's too much bloat in there.

**UPDATE** The above was provided before the update to the question, but unfortunately I can't add anything more.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Bluetooth on both the cellphone and the PC, you can get the files you want directly, via Bluetooth. It's not incredibly fast, but neither was the USB connection on my w810i (it's only USB 1.1).